# Traceback/NameError exception using SublimeText 2 with Ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2

This code form RubyMonk works in RubyMonk:

```
class Calculator
  def add(a, b)
   a + b
  end

  def subtract(a, b)
   a - b
  end
end
```

I copied it to Sublime Text 2, set the build system to Ruby, then I saved it. When I type in the console something like `add(1, 2)`, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

I couldn't find a solution to this. I tried reinstalling Sublime Text 2, tried the beta of ST3, tried other code which I know to be good (same error), etc., and nothing is working. Any ideas?

EDIT: On the suggestion of another user, I tried:

```
Calculator.new.add(1, 2)
```

which returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Calculator' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the sensation that you're calling the method add(1,2) for no Object at all. What I mean is, in this case, that you're not telling the Calculator to add, but just to the thin air... which does not know how to add!

Try doing th following:
`Calculator.new.add(1,2)`

And you'll be asking an instance of the Calculator to add.

Tell me if you have any doubts or if I'm completely mistaken!

EDIT: As stated by texasbruce, ST2 console is Python. Therefore, the solution is the following:
Add `puts Calculator.new.add(1,2)` in the code and hit `Ctrl+B` to launch Ruby.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried it and got the following:>>> Calculator.new.add(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Calculator' is not defined

Comment: Silly me. The puts command worked. Many thanks to you and texasbruce! Now, to figure out how to set console to Ruby...

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 console is python console, not ruby.

Additionally your ruby code is incorrect.

Comment: Why is the code incorrect?
Furthermore, ST2 console can be set to ruby.

Comment: @Sikian I am very obliged to hear how you can set the console to ruby

Comment: @Sikian and you need to do `Calculator.new.add(1,2)`

Comment: That's what I was suggesting, but I think it's better to have it in the file.

Comment: I downvoted at first because I thought it did not give any information to the question.

Comment: @Sikian are you planning to give it back?

Comment: @texasbruce well, it looks more like a comment to me as well.

Comment: @texasbruce If you edit the original post, I'll be able to give it back :)

Comment: @Sikian while you failed to give the right reason why the error is like that? It's fine, just keep it there.

Comment: The error was being given by the fact that he was not calling the correct method. Why so grumpy?

Comment: @Sikian It is a stacktrace error generated by python, not even a ruby error. nvm